# TypeError: Cannot read property 'AwsCredentialsProvider' of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

Been trying to test out the `aws-iot-device-sdk-v2` library for a bit. I am currently trying to test out the [sample app](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/blob/main/samples/node/pub_sub/index.ts) provided by the AWS dev team. I am trying to test out the system incrementally. This is the code I have tested so far:

```
import { mqtt, auth, http, io, iot } from 'aws-iot-device-sdk-v2';

const client_bootstrap = new io.ClientBootstrap();
        
let config_builder = iot.AwsIotMqttConnectionConfigBuilder.new_with_websockets({
    region: 'us-west-2',
    credentials_provider: auth.AwsCredentialsProvider.newDefault(client_bootstrap)
});

config_builder.with_clean_session(false);
config_builder.with_endpoint('example.com');
config_builder.with_client_id(1);
        
const config = config_builder.build();
const client = new mqtt.MqttClient(client_bootstrap);
const connection = client.new_connection(config);

await connection.connect();
```

When running this on the AWS console, I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'AwsCredentialsProvider' of undefined`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: 'auth' is undefined.....why? That I don't know.  I see the import, but that doesn't seem to be creating its object.  Do you need to initialize 'auth' first before using it?

Comment: I don't think that is a requirement. Even in the demo I linked, it doesn't look like they are initializing auth for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to identify why I couldn't use `AwsCredentialsProvider` as expected but found a work-around. Instead, I was able to initialize the builder with const `config_builder = iot.AwsIotMqttConnectionConfigBuilder.new_with_websockets();`. Anyway, didn't figure out why I couldn't utilize `AwsCredentialsProvider` as expected. Might be something to look into if the dev team has time.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same issue when running this example **in browser** and found the reason :

'aws-iot-device-sdk-v2' just import these 5 classes directly form aws-crt

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/blob/main/lib/index.ts

while in aws-crt, it's implementation for browser is in a sub folder ,
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-nodejs/tree/main/lib/browserm, and it don't include 'auth' .

so if you run these example in browser, you need to import form aws-crt's subfolder, and skip 'auth':

```
import { mqtt, http, io, iot } from 'aws-crt/dist.browser/browser';
```